# "Je vais chercher les enfants"

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

Que comprenez-vous si je dis:

> Je vais chercher les enfants.

sans plus de contexte? Ou bien: quels sont les sens possibles suivant le contexte? Y-a-t'il des variations régionales? (on me dit que l'un des sens est plus commun dans l'est de la France).

Answer (score 6):

En tant que franco-canadien, la signification qui me vient immédiatement à l'esprit en entendant cette phrase serait que vous allez récupérer des enfants quelque part (par exemple en voiture) :

> Je vais chercher les enfants à l'école, pendant ce temps, occupe-toi de préparer le repas.

Une seconde signification pourrait être de tenter de retrouver les enfants, dans un contexte où on ne sait pas où ils sont.

Personnellement, je ne vois pas un large éventail d'autres significations pour cette phrase. Évidemment, comme tu l'as mentionné, ce genre de phrase qu'on utilise chaque jour peut varier d'une région à l'autre. Je ne sais pas de quelle région tu parles (tu n'as pas nommé de pays), mais au Québec, n'importe quel francophone comprendrais très bien ce que cette phrase signifie, peu importe la région, et à mon avis, c'est également une phrase qui pourrait très bien être employée en France.

Comment: Je pensais à l'est de la France. On m'a dit que cette expression était très bien comprise là-bas, mais pas forcément dans toute la France, ce qui m'a surpris. Merci de ta réponse!

Comment: Oui, cette phrase banale sera parfaitement comprise et de la même façon au quatre coins de l'hexagone (expression appréciée des mathématiciens…).

Comment: @jlliagre - quid maintenant de l'expression _je suis rendu_?

Comment: En Ontario également je comprendrais qu'il s'agissait de les ramasser.

Comment: « Je suis rendu » seul est incompréhensible en France. « Je suis rendu chercher les enfants » serait compris comme une variante dégradée de « je me suis rendu chercher les enfants » qui n'est de toute façon pas idiomatique ici. On se rend quelque part, on ne se rend pas faire quelque chose.

Comment: Il paraît que "je suis rendu" (tout seul) est une expression bretonne. Mais je ne suis pas breton.

Comment: "Je suis rendu" = "Je suis arrivé", pour certains locuteurs de la Nouvelle Aquitaine qui ignorent ce qui se passe après "Le certificat d'étude" qu'ils n'ont pas pu décrocher (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificat_d%27%C3%A9tudes_primaires) ; d'autres utilisent je suis rendu pour dire je suis fatigué/crevé ou aussi dans unsens correct :  https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22je+suis+rendu%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr&gws_rd=cr&ei=Po-4WJjjE8iNUaTWqvAE#q=%22je+suis+rendu%22&lr=lang_fr&newwindow=1&tbs=lr:lang_1fr&tbm=bks&start=30&*